# How to make a custom date picker in react-native?

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I want to make a date picker as shown in the image below. Can anyone suggest to me which npm package should I use to make such date picker?

[date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1c0L.png)

Answer (score 0):

Flatpickr is the one I use in react. You could check if it works with native